# Is there a relationship between the Singel Page Application of asp.net-mvc4, and SPA of AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Is one application can use the Singel Page Application method of ASP.NET-MVC4 on server side and SPA of AngularJs on client side?

Comment: Sure, check this out: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET MVC4 Single Page Application template in Visual Studio comes with Knockout and not Angular. You could of course rip out Knockout and use Angular instead, but then there's not much value in using the Single Page Application template.

If you want to use Angular, I would use the AngularStart template instead: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b